# How can I break the loop ? While True:

Tags: input, while-loop, sum, average, break

When do I tell python to stop looping?
If I had an infinite loop for

example:-

```
sum = 0    
counter = 0    
while True:    
    num = eval(input("type number"))    
    if num == "stop":    
        break

    sum=sum+counter
    counter=counter+1    
    avr=sum\counter     

print(avr)
```

Here is where the problem comes, in `if num=="stop":`  Won’t work with me. It gives me some kind of error. I type the number 5 and then type stop so I can calculate the average. It immediately gives me error .

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

1. `avr=sum\counter` you confused the slash with backslash - it should be:  `avr=sum/counter`
2. you're trying to `eval` the input before checking if it's a number or `"stop"` and when the user will try to "stop" the eval will crash. You should swap the order of actions to first check if the user typed in "stop" and only if they didn't, you can "eval" it. BTW, it's not recommended to use `eval` and in your case you can use `int(input_string)` instead.
3. there's a bug: `sum=sum+counter` should be: `sum=sum+num`

and last:

4. `sum` is a builtin function in python, you should not name a variable `sum` because it overrides it. You can call it `total` or something else.

Incorporating all the above, the following code works on my localhost:

```
total = 0
counter = 0
while True:
    num = input("type number:\n")
    if num == "stop":
        break

    num = int(num)
    total = total + num
    counter = counter + 1
    avr = total / counter

print(avr)
```